# Get this person's score and better with people belonging to the same state mysqli php

Tags: php, json, sql-order-by

First i present want I want to accomplish with an example. Then I'll show the code written this far, but the code only deals with the first part of the problem.

In this example the 'name' is Elsa. So initially, `$name` and `$state` are equal to 'Elsa' and 'Washington' respectively

```
$name = $_POST["name"]; ///Is equal to 'Elsa'
$state = $_POST["state"]; ///Is equal to 'Washington'
```

The name of the table is 'table'

```
+-----+------------+--------+------------+------+
| ids | Player     |  score |   State    | Age  |
+-----+------------+--------+------------+------+
|   1 | Mike       |   1067 | Arizona    |  30  |
|   2 | Lit        |    970 | Washington |  25  |
|   3 | Sara Leman |     53 | California |  17  |    
|   4 | Ted        |    782 | Washington |  22  |
|   5 | Kralem     |    589 | Florida    |  36  |
|   6 | MrDud      |    953 | Washington |  17  |
|   7 | Gregs      |    752 | Arizona    |  38  |
|   8 | Batman     |     67 | New York   |  16  |
|   9 | Fox        |    673 | Washington |  34  |
|  10 | Hans       |    500 | Washington |  23  | 
|  11 | Elsa       |    552 | Washington |  28  |
|  12 | Britta     |    400 | Washington |  31  |
+-----+------------+--------+------------+------+
```

//1. Select everyone from Elsa's state i.e. Washington

```
+-----+------------+--------+------------+
| ids | Player     |  score |   State    |
+-----+------------+--------+------------+
|   2 | Lit        |    970 | Washington |
|   4 | Ted        |    782 | Washington |
|   6 | MrDud      |    953 | Washington |
|   9 | Fox        |    673 | Washington |
|  10 | Hans       |    500 | Washington |
|  11 | Elsa       |    552 | Washington |
|  12 | Britta     |    400 | Washington |
+-----+------------+--------+------------+
```

//2. Sort them by their scores

```
+-----+------------+--------+
| ids | Player     |  score |
+-----+------------+--------+
|   2 | Lit        |    970 |
|   6 | MrDud      |    953 |
|   4 | Ted        |    782 |
|   9 | Fox        |    673 |
|  11 | Elsa       |    552 |
|  10 | Hans       |    500 |
|  12 | Britta     |    400 |
+-----+------------+--------+
```

//////This is how far my code currently takes me

//////This is the last tricky part that I need solved
//3. Select players with Elsa's score or better, this implies that Britta disappears

```
+-----+------------+--------+
| ids | Player     |  score |
+-----+------------+--------+
|   2 | Lit        |    970 |
|   6 | MrDud      |    953 |
|   4 | Ted        |    782 |
|   9 | Fox        |    673 |
|  11 | Elsa       |    552 |
+-----+------------+--------+
```

//Done. So what I'm really interested in is this Table below

```
+------------+--------+
| Player     |  score |
+------------+--------+
| Lit        |    970 |
| MrDud      |    953 |
| Ted        |    782 |
| Fox        |    673 |
| Elsa       |    552 |
+------------+--------+
```

Here is the code

```php
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql_host","mysql_user","mysql_password","mysql_database");


$name = $_POST["name"];
$state = $_POST["state"];



$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE state = ? ORDER BY score");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $state);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $name, $score);


$result_array=array();

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
//Here I want to create the array such that I can turn it into Json format below
    }

echo json_encode($result_array);
mysqli_close($con);
exit;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want users with lower score than Elsa, then you can sort them out in the query, like so

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE state = ? AND score >= (SELECT score FROM table WHERE name = 'Elsa') ORDER BY score
```

Of course instead of using the name to identify Elsa I'd recommend you send her ID along in the form and use that instead.

Comment: `name >= 'Elsa'` should that not be `name = 'Elsa'`??

Comment: You are correct @RiggsFolly I had misplaced the `>` :) thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.Player,t1.score 
   from table t1, 
        (select state, score from table where state = ? and player = ? ) t
   where t1.state=t.state and t1.score >= t.score 
   order by score desc
```